# How to retrieve certain string in text file and sort based on element in string?

Tags: java, sorting, hashset

I'm attempting to display a list of elements from a txtfile, and then sort the list according to the date of each record. I've used a hashset to load the txtfile completely and that works.

The main problem is that I can't seem to find a method to sort the txtfile and each record according to the dates contained under each record.

```
btnPrintList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

// File path & name

Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).resolve("vehicle.txt");

try {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
   FileReader(path.toFile()));

   Set<String> carsPrint = new HashSet<>();

    String line = reader.readLine();
      while (line != null) {                 
            System.out.println("processing line: " + line);

        if (line.trim().contains("-")) {
          String[] words = line.split("");
                    }

        if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
          String[] words = line.split("");

                    }

        line = reader.readLine();

            }

        } 
              catch (IOException e1) {
        block
           e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

Here is the textfile being referred to

```
a, Honda Jazz, Hatchback, grey, 20000, none, manual, 8000, 2018-09-01, 2018-10-04,
b, Mercedes Citan, Van, small, white, 35000, front damage, manual, 9500, 2018-11-04,
c, Ford Transit, Van, small, black, 60000, none, automatic, 7300, 2018-11-01,
d, Lexus IS, Saloon, white, 23000, indent on passenger door, automatic, 18100, 2019-01-02,
e, Lexus IS, Saloon, dark blue, 6000, none, manual, 26100, 2018-10-04, 2018-10-14,
f, Mercedes Citan, Van, small, white, 35900, front windscreen damage, automatic, 10000, 2018-08-04,
g, Lexus NX, SUV, dark blue, 12000, none, automatic, 31000,
h, Ford SMax, MPV, red, 70000, none, manual, 11000, 2017-01-13,
i, Vauxhall Movano, Van, large, white, 60000, rear windscreen damage, manual, 5000, 2019-01-10, 2019-03-01,
j, Vauxhall Insignia, Saloon, green, 45000, none, automatic, 10800, 2018-08-10, 2019-03-05,
k, Vauxhall Insignia, Saloon, red, 40000, none, manual, 10200, 2018-08-10,
l, Vauxhall Movano, Van, large, silver, 60000, none, automatic, 8800,
m, BMW 3, Saloon, black, 49000, door damage, manual, 9500, 2019-03-01, 2019-03-05,
n, Ford SMax, MPV, red, 70000, none, automatic, 3800,
o, Mercedes EClass, Coupe, yellow, 25000, none, automatic, 10400, 2018-03-08, 2019-03-02,
p, Jaguar FType, Coupe, silver, 3000, none, automatic, 52000, 2018-03-01,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the hashset structure cannot be sorted. It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. (from [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html))

But you can use ArrayList instead:

```
List<?> sortedCarsPrint  = new ArrayList<>(carsPrint);
sortedCarsPrint.sort((o1,o2) -> o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime()));
```

Comment: How can your sort possibly know to sort based on the date field contained in each line?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! I've added the code you've suggested in place of where the hashset was. It seems like it should work, but I'm getting the following error "The method getDateTime() is undefined for the type capture#2-of ?". I'm unsure what this means exactly.

Comment: It's just a way to get date from your object. This getter method you need to implement on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm pretty new to Java, and I think this will fit what I need if I can get it to work, I just have no idea what to do for a getter function. 

Is that assigning o1 and o2 to an object?

Comment: No problem. The Getter Method getDateTime() should return the date of object (for example 2018-09-01). We'll need that date later to sort the list. It would be best if you wrapped the saved records in a Car object with attributes such as brand, model, color, mileage, date of production. This will make it easier for you to work. (o1,o2) -> o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime()) is using lambda expression sort. You can read about it here. https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/

Comment: Thank you, again! So it would seem that I could be using a similar method to that in the first example provided in that link, where I'm adding to the array like so?

`
private static List<Developer> getDevelopers() {

  List<Developer> result = new ArrayList<Developer>();

  result.add(new Developer("mkyong", new BigDecimal("70000"), 33));
  result.add(new Developer("alvin", new BigDecimal("80000"), 20));
  result.add(new Developer("jason", new BigDecimal("100000"), 10));
  result.add(new Developer("iris", new BigDecimal("170000"), 55));
  
  return result;

 }`

Comment: Okay, I've tried and tried, but I can't get anything to work. :(

You mentioned wrapping the records depending on their attributes, though the records themselves vary in the number of fields depending on whether the car type of the vehicle is a Van or not. I'm honestly just completely stuck. I don't really know how to proceed from where we began earlier, even after reading the attached link. :/